# Does a Cassandra Spark worker still have to marshal locally read data?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

I read somewhere that Datastax Search nodes run Solr in-process which means that local data can be passed between Cassandra and Solr in memory.

I was wondering whether this was also the case with Cassandra Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark works completely separated from Cassandra. It's a matter of Spark's driver to Cassandra, not in-process communication. So yes it have to marshal data

Comment: That's a pity. If the Spark worker were able to communicate in memory with its local Cassandra node the impact on performance would be huge.

Comment: It's stated about driver's "data locality awareness" - look at slide 47 http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/cassandra-community-webinar

Comment: I should have made it more clear that I was talking about DSE Analytics, not Cassandra and Spark running separately. Since a DSE Analytics node is started with a single command I was hoping that Spark would be run in process. Perhaps one for the future?